# Transformation of Random variable $Y=-2\ln(F(x))$

Tags: probability, transformation

Let $X$ is a continuous Random variable. with strictly increasing function cumulative distribution function $F(x)$.
Find and recognise the distribution of random variable $Y=-2\ln(F(x))$.
I need some help here please.

Comment: Can we assume $F$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes X is continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy if $F$ is continuous. In that case $P(F(X)\leq t)=P(X\leq F^{-1}(t))=F(F^{-1}(t))=t$ for $0<t<1.$ So, $F(X)\sim U(0,1).$ $P(-2\log F(X)\leq y/2)=P(\log F(X)\geq -y/2)=P(F(X)\geq e^{-y/2})=1-e^{-y/2}$ for $y>0.$ So, $Y\sim Exp(2)$ or $Y\sim \chi^2_2.$

But if $F$ is not continuous, i.e, there is jump in $F$, then $F(X)$ might not be uniformly distributed.

Comment: We can say $P\{Y \leq y\}=1-F(G(e^{-y/2)}))$ whether or not $F$ is continuous, where $G(t)=\inf \{x:F(x) \geq t\}$. If $F$ is continuous then $F\circ G$ is the identity function.

Comment: @kotsossgouras The first $y/2$ is a misprint; it should say $y$.

Comment: how we can show that F^-1(F(X))=X ??